# ingress-nginx-controller-admission: what does it do? Why is it there

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am new to Kubernetes.  Setting up nginx-ingress in a test cluster. One of our senior people rolled by and noticed the following.

```
# kubectl get services
...
ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      xx.xxx.xxx.xxx   <none>        443/TCP
...
```

What's that, he asked.  Get rid of it if you don't need it.

Before I rip it out and maybe get cripple my test cluster .. what *is* ingress-nginx-controller-admission and why do I need it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the service for the validating webhook that ingress-nginx includes. If you remove it, you'll be unable to create or update Ingress objects unless you also remove the webhook configuration.

tl;dr it's important, no touchy

Comment: Also if your "senior people" make a habit of this, maybe steer them towards Kubernetes Slack so they can ask themselves and maybe not send you down wildly unsafe goose chases.

Comment: Probably worth adding link from other answer to yours, as the two answers point to the same docs

Comment: As a beginner, I hardly understand the context based on the comments. @strongjz's comments helped a lot, hence downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

> Because the ingress controller works using the synchronization loop
> pattern, it is applying the configuration for all matching objects. In
> case some Ingress objects have a broken configuration, for example a
> syntax error in the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet
> annotation, the generated configuration becomes invalid, does not
> reload and hence no more ingresses will be taken into account.
>
> To prevent this situation to happen, the nginx ingress controller
> optionally exposes a validating admission webhook server to ensure the
> validity of incoming ingress objects. This webhook appends the
> incoming ingress objects to the list of ingresses, generates the
> configuration and calls nginx to ensure the configuration has no
> syntax errors.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#avoiding-outage-from-wrong-configuration